# Is the ability to export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM as .reg files a security concern?

Tags: windows-10, ntlm, registry

I am concerned that if it is possible to copy these as `.reg` files (without privs) and then (on another machine) reverse the `.hiv` files from them... this would probably be bad, which makes me think it's likely not possible.

Has this/is this done to anyone's knowledge? I found some tools that claim the ability to go from an exported `.reg` to a `.hiv` but perhaps exported `.reg` do not contain sufficient information to obtain the complete hive (and included sensitive local user info).